# Missing output after execvp on Ubuntu 22?

Tags: python-3.x, shell, execvp

I have a short Python code (main.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash                                                                 
import os                                                                       
import subprocess                                                               
print(os.getpid())                                                              
os.execvp("ls", ["ls", "-a"])                                                   
print("hello")
```

When I run it I can see the terminal output of `os.getpid()` and `os.execvp` commands, but no `print("hello")`.

However when I have another file (another.py) with the content of:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash                                                                                                                 
print("hello")
```

And then change main.py to be:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash                                                                 
import os                                                                       
import subprocess                                                               
print(os.getpid())                                                              
os.execvp("python3", ["python3", "another.py"])
```

Then I can see the output of `os.getpid()` and `print("hello")`

What is the idea behind execvp?

Comment: You should `os.fork` first

Comment: `os.execvp` replaces the current program by a new program, that's why `print('hello')` doesn't get executed

Comment: @jvx8ss but why `print("hello")` is not taken into that "new program"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple script that illustrates `fork` `exec` and `wait`

```py
import os

print('this will run once')

pid = os.fork()
# duplicates the current process after this point

if pid < 0:
    print('error forking')
    exit()

print('this will run twice')

if pid == 0:
    # we are inside child process
    print('hello from child')
    os.execvp("echo", ["echo", "hello from echo"])
    print('this will not run because child process has been completely replaced by echo process')
else:
    os.wait()
    # wait child process to exit
    print('hello from parent')
```

Comment: Great example! Am I correct to say that everything after os.execvp() will not be called, so if I wish to include some code after os.execvp() I should call "some code" from within the os.execvp("some code", ["some code", "and args"]?

Comment: I didn't understand correctly the "some code" part but if you want to run code after `exec`, you should place it in the `else:` block (aka parent process), also use `os.wait()` if order of execution is important

Comment: your response is very clear, thank you very much!